# Solving SUR with (N-1) Equations

Tags: econometrics, seemingly-unrelated-regressions

**Problem**

I'm estimating a seemingly unrelated regression (SUR) with identical regressors where my dependent variable, $y_{cit}$, is a share of total across $c$, such that, $\sum_{c=1}^5 y_{cit}$ = 1. In this setup my dependent variable is a proportion, $c$, of total output for each, $i$,in each year, $t$.

In a SUR model, we assume the error terms in the system of equations are *contemporaneously correlated*; that is, the errors across equations are correlated with one another where an increase in one decreases/increases another.

A problem arises when estimating this system of equations because the error-covariance matrix is *singular*, or residuals sum to zero across equations. Because of this problem, we can't solve the feasible generalized least square (FGLS). To solve for the system, it is appropriate leave out one $(N-1)$ equation where the N$^{th}$ equation can be derived by summing the coefficient matrix rows and columns to equal zero. This allows me to estimate coefficients for the N$^{th}$ equation, but not the standard-errors (see Wooldridge (2010) section 7.7.3, or [online here p. 29](http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-c/s2013/327/EC327.S2013.nn2.pdf)).

**Question**

How can I estimate standard errors for the N$^{th}$ equation?